# Flight to Baghdad layover in Jordan?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, transit, layovers, jordan

I used to live in Jordan between 2000 and 2002
I left the country in 2002 and they told me I cannot enter Jordan again for 4 years.
I am now a British citizen.

Few months ago I went on a holiday from the UK to Jordan. When I arrived at the airport 
they didn't allow me to enter as they said you can't enter Jordan because of the 4 year ban, even though it's been much longer than 4 years. After waiting few hours and talking with the officials they allowed me to go through and told me to consult a police station about the issue to resolve it.

I didn't have enough time to go to the police station.

This year I've booked a flight to Baghdad with the Jordanian airlines. The flight from Heathrow to Baghdad has a layover of 10 hours in Jordan before it goes to Baghdad. During this 10 hours we'll be taken to a hotel to stay until our flight to Baghdad starts.

I was wondering would I get another problem at the airport in Jordan this time as well, or would it not matter this time because it's just a layover and I'm not visiting Jordan itself?
I've already booked my flight and I'm really worried that I might encounter another problem in Jordan.

Comment: If you were told to go to the police and to resolve an open issue, and you haven't done so, why would you expect any different result next time? Anyway, there's no way this can be answered. You can contact the Jordanian embassy in London and ask them.

Comment: It was because I entered Jordan for 1 day only at the time to travel by car from Jordan to Iraq, that's why I didn't have enough time to do. My question is if they will care about it even if it is just a transit, as I'm not entering Jordanian soil just waiting in the airport for plane changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, If it is a transit layover in the transit Hotel then you will not face any problems since transit passengers do not pass the immigration or stamp passports...

Any way, being from the middle east I know how things are slow here sometimes when it comes to this kind of situations. I personally face the same problem in Egypt. There is a guy who is banned from Egypt and have the same name as mine and up to now whenever I go to Egypt I must spend more than 1 hour every time until I am cleared. So most likely if you will pass immigration then you will be held for sometime just like what happened with you.

Comment: But he says he'll be taken to an hotel during the layover, doesn't it mean he'd have to go through the immigration? And it seems that in this case its the actual OP who was banned, not someone else with a similar name...

Comment: The hotel could be inside the airport (transit hotel). which will not require entrance to Jordan.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But like littleadv said I'll be taken to a hotel, which is arranged by the airline because the layover is 10 hours. So does that mean I need to go through the immigration?

Comment: The hotel is outside the airport as I was told

Comment: So, get prepared for the same thing :) بالتوفيق

Comment: شكرا اخويه.. بس تفتكر انو ممكن ما يسمحولنه ندخل للمطار ابد ونعمل الترانزيت ولا مجرد روتين وبعدها بيطلعونه عادي؟

Comment: اي والله العرب بيموتو في التاخير هههه.. والحاجه الغريبه انو هم اعطوني الي ولعائلتي ابعاد لمدة 4 سنين من سنة 2002.. يعني الابعاد المفروض خلص سنة 2006.. مشكور اخويه ما قصرت